# Controlling pushing notifications sound inside the App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I was wondering if it is possible to turn push notification sound off inside the App itself without the user going into the iphone settings?  I want to give the user the ability to turn notification sound off inside the App itself so no new push notification will make a noise when the App is closed or in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the sound ID that is going to be played in the notification metadata. If you keep track of user (like having a server database) you could handle this by a server flag and send an empty sound notification when the user has turned that off. Silent notifications where added in iOS 7 so this should become a silent notification.

Comment: Am I able to turn off sound notification for push notifications without doing anything server related or going into iPhone settings? I don't think I can, I am just curious.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html check the silent notifications to see what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to only send silent push notifications (has nothing in the aps portion of the payload except the `content-available` flag). Then you could have your app translate that into a `UILocalNotification`. This would allow you to turn the sound on/off in your app using `soundName` property on `UILocalNotification`.

Note: this will only work on iOS 7 and up.

More on silent push notifications:

- [Objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html)
- [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)